# redirecting back to different object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem for redirecting back after an action.
My condition is this:
Client, Volunteer, and staff has many next of kin. After creating a new next of kin, I want to redirect back to edit page of a particular client/volunteer/staff.

my current solution is this.

For the link to add

```
<%= link_to new_admin_people_next_of_kin_path(source: source,
source_id: source_id),
class: 'js-btn-add btn btn-success btn-sm' do %>
  Add New Next of Kin
<% end %>
```

where
source = :client/:staff/:volunteer
source_id = id(primary key) or the staff/volunteer/client

my new method

```
def new
  @person = Person.new
  @person.source = params[:source]
  @person.source_id = params[:source_id]
end
```

later I will pass source and source_id as hidden parameter.

my people_controller create method(because next of kin is a person)

```
def create
  if params[:source] == 'client'
    @client = Client.find(params[:source_id])
    @pnok = @client.people_next_of_kin.build
  elsif params[:source] == 'volunteer'
    @volunteer = Volunteer.find(params[:source_id])
    @pnok = @volunteer.people_next_of_kin.build
  elsif params[:source] == 'staff'
    @staff = Staff.find(params[:source_id])
    @pnok = @staff.people_next_of_kin.build
  else
    @pnok = PeopleNextOfKin.new
  end
  @person = @pnok.build_next_of_kin

  Person.transaction do
    @person.update_attributes(create_params)
    @person.save(validate: false)
  end
end
```

as you can see, it's not really clean and hardcoded. I have read on polymorphic path, but I can't really find a way to use that for my solution as I need to build a new next of kin first and I cannot pass in an object in link_to or redirect_to, and then there's also a problem whereby the next of kin is not saved yet in database, so I cannot use person.find.
any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tough to see what you are after from your example. I would guess that you want to redirect back to the staff / volunteer / client page and there would be a Parent / Child relationship with a NOK.

However, it's unclear what your models look like. For example, you might be using single table inheritance and polymorphism because these are all "People", or you might have the relationships in your models. I think the solution depends on which path you take.

For example, you might use something like this:

```
 def Client
   has_many :noks
 end
```

If you had that, you could build the empty :nok record and then redirect back to the :client, and let the Rails / ActiveRecord internals manage the relationship. For example, the Client #show page may have places to list all Next of Kins that enumerates all of the kin.

Summary: I think you are trying to do too much in your controller without using models the way that RoR supports.

Comment: Client/volunteer/staff(which inherits person) and next of kin(which is an alias for person) is related by many to many using people next of kin as the join table. People next of kin also has several other attribute, so I need to build pnok fisrt before creating a nok